# How to store data based on role levels using firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-roles

I am currently working on my final year project using react and firebase,

I have been working with firebase and been able to store the data directly,

but now I want to give role-based access to the users.

This is the[* hierarchy *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onJhk.png) of users to store all data which is received and topmost level user i.e ***principal can read and write all the data ( principal, vice principal, hod, faculties)*** branches, *lower level user i.e **vice-principal should not be able to read and write the data(fields in particular) associated with principal** but can read and write the data associated with(***vice principal, hod, faculties***)* branches. and so on.....

[to be more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/109KB.png)

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase has no user roles at all and nothing built in that supports roles. Roles would be determined by the structure of your firebase and then you would craft rules to support those roles. There are a a *lot* of posts here on SO about working with users in Firebase and a quick search will provide a wealth of answers. Search for `[firebase]user roles`. Also, take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a user in the system copy their uid into a user collection and assign the user a role when they are created. Then in the future query that user by their uid to see what role they have and give them access to the content/functionality in question, based on the query response.

Comment: This is a high-level overview of what you have to do. If you have a more specific question, ask a more specific question.